# Clean Install VS Compile Performance Problems

Tags: performance, visual-studio, compilation

**Problem**

VS takes 25 seconds to compile even a brand new un-edited empty console app project

[image: Screenshot of compile problem]

**What I have tried**

I noticed this performance problem recently, but i'm not sure exactly when it started, so to play it safe I have taken the following actions ...

- Disabled any redundant / not needed services running in windows
- Re-installed VS 2015 Enterprise
- Deleted everything in %temp%
- deleted everything in "C:\Windows\Prefetch"
- tried a compile with a brand new console app project on a different physical drive to my usual projects
- Disabled Windows defender (no other firewalls / AV installed): http://ardalis.com/speed-up-visual-studio-build-times
- Suggestion (option doesn't seem to be visible in C# projects): [visual studio 2015 build takes long time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33159191/visual-studio-2015-build-takes-long-time)
- Increase max parallel projects (compiles n number of projects every 25 seconds instead of 1 every 25 seconds), other setting had no impact: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1042975/Tips-to-Improve-Visual-Studio-Build-Performance

**Some key observations**

- The problem seems to only affect VS
- Resource usage is low for cpu, ram, disk, and network
- PC specs are fairly high (6th gen i7, SSD, 16GB ram)

**Update**

I got talking to some Microsoft guys by email and they have narrowed in down to the "roslyn compiler server" that VS uses to do "shared resourcing" during the build process in some way (i don't fully understand the full details myself)

The long and short of it was that you can figure out if you have the same problem by doing this using a "Developer Command Prompt" ...

[image]

... the first line sets an environment variable telling roslyn to log its activities in to file which for me produced this ...

```
--- PID=8144 TID=9 Ticks=17865781: CommandLine = ' /noconfig'
--- PID=8144 TID=9 Ticks=17865781: BuildResponseFile = '/nowarn:1701,1702 /nostdlib+ /platform:anycpu32bitpreferred /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:DEBUG;TRACE /highentropyva+ /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\Microsoft.CSharp.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\mscorlib.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.Core.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.Data.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.Net.Http.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.Xml.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.Xml.Linq.dll" /debug+ /debug:full /filealign:512 /optimize- /out:obj\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe /ruleset:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\\Rule Sets\MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset" /subsystemversion:6.00 /target:exe /utf8output Program.cs Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs "C:\Users\PaulW\AppData\Local\Temp\.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2.AssemblyAttributes.cs"'
--- PID=8144 TID=9 Ticks=17865781: Attempting to create process 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\VBCSCompiler.exe'
--- PID=8144 TID=9 Ticks=17865781: Successfully created process with process id 2080
--- PID=8144 TID=9 Ticks=17865781: Attempt to open named pipe 'PaulW.True.GE6kSCQEbMXsysJ19S0qExhvU5zqX2Bc34kg0RSsgmc'
--- PID=8144 TID=9 Ticks=17865781: Attempt to connect named pipe 'PaulW.True.GE6kSCQEbMXsysJ19S0qExhvU5zqX2Bc34kg0RSsgmc'
--- PID=8144 TID=9 Ticks=17890781: Connecting to server timed out after 20000 ms
```

.. Microsoft noted that the last line was key here, it seems that the "compiler server" in VS is doing something it shouldn't and thus not responding to the build process requests correctly resulting in this delay.

Comment: is antivirus disabled? same effect on other drives?

Comment: None installed except windows defender, I can disable that I suppose and test again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking the problem above happens because of that timeout in the roslyn log.

The timeout happens probably because the compiler service is dying for some reason so, if you go open up the file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\VBCSCompiler.exe" when it runs, the chances are you'll get an exception, and reading that will tell you more about the exact cause of the problem.

Thanks to Jared Parsons @ Microsoft for the key info on this one :)